# How to refer to an Angular component's full template setting CSS without referring to any tags?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular2-template

My usual setup for each view is an outer DIV that I style as the base background etc.

```
<div class="outer">
  <!-- Actual stuff in here -->
</div>
```

Then, in the SASS, I refer to it like so.

```
div.outer { ... }
```

That adds one lever of indent and seems like an unnecessary (though minor) increment in complexity. So I wonder if it's possible to add a style to the template itself. Partly, to lower the complexity. Partly, because I'm going to have text-only elements with no tags at all.

Is it possible to set the style of template from SASS files if there are no tags, only text in it?

Comment: Your text elements will surely be in `<p>` or other semantic tags that you can target though right?

Comment: @SamWillis Negative. They won't. (Or, rather, they might be not.) And I still want to style them a bit for convenience of the reader. (Also, I was curious if it could be done, too. Academic curiosity.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply styling to the component host element with the [:host](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host) selector:

```
:host {
  color: red;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sucshz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss) for a demo.